# React does not redirect after first login but refreshes page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on firebase authentication. I have made login, logout(on home), home pages. All are working fine. But when I try to login after I have changed something in router or in my code it works perfectly, that is redirects to Home. But when I login after logout, It does not work and reloads the same login page.

Also when isLoggedIn is set true after first try, it reloads login component. When I manually change url to `/home` then it works fine.

Here is my code.

App js

```
import Signup from "./Signup";
import Login from "./Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../ProtectedRoutes";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route
            path="home"
            element={
              <ProtectedRoutes
                isLoggedIn={JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn"))}
              >
                <Home />
              </ProtectedRoutes>
            }
          />
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="signup" element={<Signup />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Login

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card, Form, Alert, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebaserc";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value
    )
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
        console.log(user);
        localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn"))) {
          navigate("/home");
        }
        setError("");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container
        className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        style={{
          minHeight: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="w-100"
          style={{
            maxWidth: "400px",
          }}
        >
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <h2 className="text-center mb-3">Login</h2>
              {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group id="email" className="mb-2">
                  <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group id="password" className="mb-2">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100 mt-2" type="submit">
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
            New here? <Link to="/signup">Signup</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Signup

```
import React from "react";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Card, Form, Alert, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebaserc";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      emailRef.current.value,
      passwordRef.current.value
    )
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log(user);
        setError("");
        navigate("/home");
        localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", true);
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error.message);
        // ..
      });
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container
        className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
        style={{
          minHeight: "100vh",
        }}
      >
        <div
          className="w-100"
          style={{
            maxWidth: "400px",
          }}
        >
          <Card>
            <Card.Body>
              <h2 className="text-center mb-3"> Sign Up</h2>
              {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Group id="email" className="mb-2">
                  <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group id="password" className="mb-2">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
                </Form.Group>
                <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100 mt-2" type="submit">
                  Sign Up
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
          <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
            Already have an account <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

Home

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { auth } from "../firebaserc";
import { signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleLogout = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        // Sign-out successful.
        localStorage.removeItem("isLoggedIn");
        navigate("/login", { replace: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
        console.log(error.message);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      Home
      <Button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Protected Routes

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoutes = ({ isLoggedIn, children }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you want to make a React App refresh ,
Simply

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
}, [doSomething, IsAuthenticated ]);
```

once this values change it will update this component

This value need to be observable

firebase gives you that

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

and with react you can also make

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    handleLogin(user);
  } else {
    Logout();
  }
});


function Logout() {
  setAuthintecated(false)
};
```

Also here some resource for you

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-firebase-authentication-and-crud-operations/

GoodLuck

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out getItem from localhost was slower hence causing null value to reach protected route first. Checking with firebase onAuthStateChanged solved the issue.